# Injecting a mock service for an angularjs controller test

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to test a controller that depends on a service I built myself.  I'd like to mock this service since the service talks to the DOM.

Here's my current test:

```
describe('Player Controllers', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        this.addMatchers({
            toEqualData: function (expected) {
                return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
            }
        });
    });

    describe('TestPSPlayerModule', function () {
        var $httpBackend, scope, ctrl;

        beforeEach(module('PSPlayerModule'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller(PlayerController, { $scope: scope });
        }));

        it('should request a clip url from the server when clipClicked is called', function () {
            expect(1).toBe(1);
        });
    });

});
```

My controller looks like this:

```
w.PlayerController = function ($scope, $http, $window, speedSlider, $location) {
    ...
}
```

so it's the speedSlider I want to mock.

I had the idea to use a module I created in my test code that could provide a faked implementation of the speed slider, so I added the following to the top of the test.js file:

```
module('TestPSPlayerModule', []).factory('speedSlider', function () {
    return = {
       ...
    };
});
```

and then list that module in the beforeEach() call instead of the concrete one, but if I do that I get the following error:

```
Injector already created, can not register a module!
```

So I figure there must be a better way for me to provide a mock implementation of one of my services.  Something I can perhaps use sinon.js for....

Comment: Have you seen this documentation? http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.testing_services Where `$window` is mocked out.  It is a rather simple example, but it might provide a template for what you want to do.

Comment: @NoahFreitas The link you provided is now dead

Comment: @StephaneEybert, looks like it's been moved to and updated here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#unit-testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure when you use module after its definition that you don't have the extra brackets. 
So `module('TestPSPlayer')` instead of `module('TestPSPlayer',[])`.

Answer (score 40):

Also be sure you're not trying to do this inside an inject function call:

This will throw the error:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function(someOtherService) {
        module('theApp', function($provide) {
            myMock = {foo: 'bar'};
            $provide.value('myService', myServiceMock);
            someOtherService.doSomething();
        });
    }));
```

This will not:

```
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('theApp', function($provide) {
            myMock = {foo: 'bar'};
            $provide.value('myService', myServiceMock);
        });

        inject(function(someOtherService) {
           someOtherService.doSomething();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nesting `module()` inside `inject()` is not what causes the error. In fact, all `module()` calls must be _before_ `inject()`.

Comment: @tobi, because `inject()` uses modules that _have been_ already registered. Here is the implementation: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2388.

Answer (score 4):

In my case this didn't worked:

```
beforeEach(module('user'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($http) {
}));

beforeEach(module('community'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
}));
```

I've changed to this to make it to work:

```
beforeEach(module('user'));
beforeEach(module('community'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($http) {
}));
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
}));
```

Comment: this explains that inject should be called AFTER all the module initializations

Answer (score 0):

If your provider does not use global init you can use the original injected provider and mock it.
in the example below the testedProvider is your controller.

```
var injectedProviderMock;

beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule');
});

beforeEach(inject(function (_injected_) {
    injectedProviderMock  = mock(_injected_);
}));


var  testedProvider;
beforeEach(inject(function (_testedProvider_) {
    testedProvider = _testedProvider_;
}));

it("return value from injected provider", function () {
    injectedProviderMock.myFunc.andReturn('testvalue');
    var res = testedProvider.executeMyFuncFromInjected();
    expect(res).toBe('testvalue');
});

//mock all provider's methods
function mock(angularProviderToMock) {

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.getOwnPropertyNames(angularProviderToMock).length; i++) {
        spyOn(angularProviderToMock,Object.getOwnPropertyNames(angularProviderToMock)[i]);
    }
    return angularProviderToMock;
}
```